# I'm trying to open file, but I have faced this type of errror FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python-3.x

## how to open file wit python code

#user = ["abcdefghijklmnabcdefghijklww"]

````
user = open("notes.txt", "r")
print(user.read())
for i in user:
    print("The no of occurrences of W is ",i.count("i"))
    print("The no of occurrences of i is",i.count("n"))
    print("The no of occurrences of s is",i.count("d"))
    print("The no of occurrences of e is",i.count("i"))
    print("The no of occurrences of n is",i.count("a"))
    #print(len(user))
    break;

```I'm just trying to open file

```I have tried this methods too

# user = open(r'd:\python\notes.txt')
# print(user)
````

the error was appered:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pradeep\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\test1.py", line 98, in <module>
    user = open("notes.txt", "r")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'notes.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you will be able to **obtain the desired result** by using this piece of code. Check it out. It works for me.

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as user_f:
  # Read the contents of the file
  text = user_f.read()

  # Count the occurrence of each letter
  W_count = text.count('W')
  n_count = text.count('n')
  d_count = text.count('d')
  i_count = text.count('i')
  a_count = text.count('a')

  # Print the count for each letter
  print(f"The no of occurrences of W is : {W_count}")
  print(f"The no of occurrences of n is : {n_count}")
  print(f"The no of occurrences of d is : {d_count}")
  print(f"The no of occurrences of i is : {i_count}")
  print(f"The no of occurrences of a is : {a_count}")
```